# Rename table in Sql Server and updating references

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I need to rename a table, and add some columns to it.

This table has a PK column (Id) and a Self-referencing column (ParentId). These constraints use the old table name in their names.
There are also other tables that use this tables PK as foreign keys.

So, what would be the correct way to do this, asssuming that I need to rename TableA->TableB?

```
Drop constraints in all tables that reference TableA.Id
sp_rename 'dbo.TableA', 'TableB'
Add constraints that were dropped with new names?
```

Or, there is some other way?

Comment: Constraints are possibly not the only dependencies. How about triggers, stored procedures, dynamic queries, etc.? Getting all these references can be somewhat cumbersome. Have you logged the traffic to that table to see who uses / references this table (also for dynamic queries)?

Comment: Here is a similar question I asked [Renaming a column without breaking the scripts and stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810096/renaming-a-column-without-breaking-the-scripts-and-stored-procedures)

Comment: @Ralph There are no triggers, stored procedures, queries are generated through ORM (programmers code), so that is already up to date. This table will be offline when schema update needs to be executed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not creating a new table with the required dependencies, naming, etc. and then populating with the existing data from the old table?

Comment: @BeaglesEnd Isn't that a lot more work? I need to create tableB, copy data from TableA to TableB, create all references, constraints, indexes, PK, and then delete references, constraints, indexes, etc for TableA, and then Delete TableA. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @Goran It might be a bit more work, but you get a new clean table set up exactly how you want it set up. And, you have the legacy table to role back to if required. This is how I would approach it, but it is a matter of preference.